# Measuring the girth of a 3D object

Tags: 3d, measurement

Given I have a 3D model, do you know of any approach or algorithm that I could code to measure along and around it? If I have similar objects I would want to measure always the same section.

Even something to Google for would be enough.

Thanks

Comment: "Measure along amd around it" - What's amd? What do you want to calculate? And what does object's position have to do with it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, edited.

Comment: Do you want to measure a distance between two points on the surface of the object?

Comment: Yes, but also girth of an object at a certain point.

Comment: Sounds tough! Here is an idea: Assuming your object has some kind of direction and you can find an up vector for it, then using that vector and an arbitrary point on the surface of the object you can get a formula for a surface which is perpendicular to the object and use it to find a 2D shape of the object's profile with an approach similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646738/detecting-arbitrary-shapes. Once you have that, calculating the perimeter of that shape should be relatively simple. It's just a guess though, so I'll wait for smarter people to answer.

Comment: That's a good starting point, thanks.