# How to calculate the cross section of a tetrahedron

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a volume mesh which is actually a tetrahedral mesh. I would like to calculate the cross-section of this mesh given a plane function, saying `z = 0`. I can imagine that the cross section of a tetrahedron is either a triangle or a quadrilateral. For the first case, triangle, once I calculate the 3 cross points I can get it; but for the second case, how can I make the quadrilateral become 2 triangles? My problem is I cannot determine the diagonal of the quadrilateral.

Comment: Seems to me that you need to solve a mathematical problem, not a coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Intersect all tetrahedron edges by the plane. You will get 3 or 4 intersection points.

If 3 points then a single triangle.

If 4 points, they form a convex quadrilateral. Take any 3 points, that form a first triangle. The other triangle if formed of the fourth point and the two endpoints of the edge that has this point to its right.

Alternatively (for a more general solution), tag the intersection points with the indexes of the faces incident on the edge, and reconstruct the ring of labels.

Ex: edges are common to faces AB, CD, DA and BC; then the section is ABCD.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5105357/494747) outlines a general volume-plane intersection algorithm. It will return the vertices of the intersection in order, so it's easy to determine the diagonal of your quadrilateral.